# Having difficulties installing Caffe in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, caffe

OS: ubuntu 16.04
CUDA: 7.5
Cudnn: 5

I am following [this](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-or-15.10-OpenCV-3.1-Installation-Guide) tutorial for installing caffe with gpu.
In here, I wanted an installation of opencv 3.1. But the compilation of opencv is giving error when CUDA is already installed in the system.

The error I get on trying to `make` opencv 3.1 is :

```
/usr/include/string.h: In function ‘void* __mempcpy_inline(void*, const void*, size_t)’:
/usr/include/string.h:652:42: error: ‘memcpy’ was not declared in this scope
   return (char *) memcpy (__dest, __src, __n) + __n;
                                          ^
CMake Error at cuda_compile_generated_gpu_mat.cu.o.cmake:266 (message):
  Error generating file
  /home/cortana/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/build/modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/./cuda_compile_generated_gpu_mat.cu.o


modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/build.make:63: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_gpu_mat.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_gpu_mat.cu.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1505: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have tried changing CMakeLists.txt of opencv 3.1 by adding the line `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -D_FORCE_INLINES")` to it. Also, I checked the suggestion for changing the `/usr/include/string.h` provided [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/caffe-users/Tm3OsZBwN9Q/XKGRKNdmBAAJ). But I already have the updated version of the file.
I am unable to build opencv 3.1 and hence, Caffe.

Comment: CUDA  7.5 doesn't support Ubuntu 16 or gcc 5

Comment: I tried compiling with GCC 4.8 too, it gave the same errors

Answer (score 1):

Try with CUDA 8. It worked for me with GeForce GTX 960M on Ubuntu 16.04