# Error installing opencv 3.1.0 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, caffe

After following a few tutorial such as: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-or-15.10-OpenCV-3.1-Installation-Guide
I've encountered a problem with the installation process, This is the error:

```
[ 10%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_core
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libopencv_ts.a(ts_func.cpp.o): undefined reference to symbol '_ZNKSs4findEPKcm@@GLIBCXX_3.4'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_core.dir/build.make:832: recipe for target 'bin/opencv_perf_core' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_perf_core] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1331: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_core.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_core.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This shows up after:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -DCUDA_NVCC_FLAGS="-D_FORCE_INLINES" ..
make
```

If more information is needed just ask.

Comment: [Everyone's installing caffe right now? ;D](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39364802/5008845)

Comment: mmm I don't like coffee ;)
I need to use Tensorflow though... :/